# Vertical adjustment of symbols relative to text in legend

Tags: r, legend-properties, r-base-graphics

Is there a way to vertical align the symbols in a legend relative to the first line of the corresponding text?

```
plot(table(iris$species))
legend('right',c('A','B','long\ntext'), fill = colors(3))
```

The labels `A` and `B` are vertically aligned to the corresponding symbols, but the symbol corresponding to the the third label (`long text` with a line-break between the words) is aligned to the middle of this label.

I would prefer if the symbol would be aligned to the first line of the label (i.e. `long`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to put a blank line before the text. That way, the first line of text will be aligned with the box:

```r
pie(table(iris$Species), col = palette.colors(3, "Pastel 1"), cex = 2)
legend('right',c('A','B',' \nlong\ntext'), fill = palette.colors(3, "Pastel 1"), 
       cex = 2, box.lty = 0, y.intersp = 0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
iris <- iris
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, fill=Species)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=colors(3), labels=c('A', 'B', 'long\ntext')) +
  theme(legend.position="right", legend.justification=0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's also a nice solution for people using `ggplot2`.